# Unity Slider value isn't updating

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make progress bar in Unity

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ActivityController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;

    private void Update()
    {
        slider.value =+ 0.1f;
        Debug.Log(slider.value);
    }
}
```

slider.value is not changing or adding value

Comment: Where do you initialize the slider?

Comment: At EventSystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just a nasty typo:

```
slider.value =+ 0.1f;
```

basically means

```
slider.value = 0 + 0.1f;
```

---

What you want is

```
slider.value += 0.1f;
```

which basically means

```
slider.value = slider.value + 0.1f;
```

See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UfSO4F)